# Upgrade magento version from 1.9.2.4 to 2.0

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, migration, magento2-migration-tool

I want to upgrade magento version from 1.9.2.4 to 2.0.

How to achieve this ?

Anyone can explain the steps to achieve this.

Answer (score 6):

You can't really **upgrade** from 1.9 to 2.0.

What you can do is **migrate the installation from 1.9 to 2.0**

You can find every detail you need in the official documentation here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html

Here's a workflow diagram that will give you a good idea of what to do:

[image]